# How to get product details from Magento Database with mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database, magento-1.9

I just want to know about how to get product details from magento database tables. I know how to run MySQL Query and get results from database. But the problem is magento database, I don't know which tables should I target.

I need to retrieve:

1. SKU
2. Name
3. Short Description
4. Thumbnail
5. Category ID

But the problem is that magento have a huge database and I cannot find from which tables I can get these details.

I just need tables name from which I can get these details. Because I will be getting these details in a PHP file out of magento. So will be using mysql_query("SELECT * FROM which_table");

Please help :)

Omer

Comment: I guess this should do [*`Get All Product Attributes`*](http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/get-all-product-attributes-for-a-magento-object-using-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
echo $product->getSku() . '<br />';
echo $product->getName() . '<br />';
echo $product->getShortDescription() . '<br />';
foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $categoryID){
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryID);
    echo $category->getId() . ' - ' . $category->getName() . '<br />';
}
if($product->getImage() == 'no_selection')
{
     // PRODUCT HAVE NO IMAGE
}
else
{
     // PRODUCT HAVE IMAGE
     if (count($product->getGalleryImages()) > 0) {
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            echo $image->getLabel() . ' <br />';
        }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: I just need tables name from which I can get these details. Because I will get this details in a PHP file out of magento. So will be using mysql_query("SELECT * FROM which_table");

Answer (score 0):

The primary table in which Magento 1 stores products is `catalog_product_entity`.

However, due to [the EAV model](https://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1/) almost no useful data other than the ID is actually stored there. You will likely need to JOIN on the `eav_attribute` table to find what properties are available, and then JOIN on the `catalog_product_entity_*` tables to actually get the useful data.

For this reason, I highly suggest working within Magento itself. If the goal is to get data via a script, then look at [N98](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) or consider [writing your own Magento 1 script](https://inchoo.net/magento/php-shell-scripts-for-magento/) which you can then invoke from other scripts.